ModuleNotFoundError: No module named Exception
HelperUtils/CommonAutomationFunction_Util.py
import pywinauto

class CommonAutoLib():
    """   
    """
    _logger = None
    _autoWait = None
    _yamlContent = None

    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()
        self._logger = super()._init_logger()
        self._CommonGUILocators = self.loadAndReturnYAMLFile('GUILocators/CommonGUILocators.yaml')

LoadProfile.py
from HelperUtils.CommonAutomationFunction_Util import CommonAutoLib

CommonGUILocators = CommonAutoLib().loadAndReturnYAMLFile('GUILocators/CommonGUILocators.yaml')

I am trying to call __init__ method of CommonAutomationFunction_Util.py to LoadProfile.py. Attaching image for reference


It says No module named 'HelperUtils' which means exactly what it says

from where are you calling the script?

What is HelperUtils? If it is your own library, maybe sys.path should be extended with the correct path. Or organize your code as a package using __init__.py for the folder (it could be empty). More details are needed about this module. It is not connected with pywinauto at all. It is some very basic misunderstanding of how Python imports work.

create a class in your LoadProfile.py file and call on this from a separate main file. will look something like the following
LoadProfile.py
from HelperUtils.CommonAutomationFunction_Util import CommonAutoLib

class LoadProfile:

    def __init__(self):

        CommonGUILocators = CommonAutoLib().loadAndReturnYAMLFile('GUILocators/CommonGUILocators.yaml')

main.py
from <filePath> import LoadProfile

LoadProfile()


you didn't read the question. there's a ModuleNotFoundError triggered by importing HelperUtils.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
